# Removing Older Survey Observations for the Same Student in the Same Week

Tags: r

My dataframe contains Week 1 and Week 12 course survey results for individuals, and some individuals have taken the Week 1 survey twice like student #100 below.  There are other vectors in the df beyond those show in the example, but I want to delete the oldest observations for these individuals.

```
St#   Week  Date    
100     1   15-Jun
100     1   18-Jun  
100     12  25-Aug  
101     1   17-Jun  
101     12  25-Aug
102     12  26-Aug
```

Also, how may I delete observations where students have only taken the Week 1 or the Week 12 like student #102?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here are `data.table` and `plyr` solutions.

```
dat <- read.table(text = "St   Week  Date
100     1   15-Jun
100     1   18-Jun
100     12  25-Aug
101     1   17-Jun
101     12  25-Aug
102     12  26-Aug  ", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dat$Date <- as.Date(paste(dat$Date, "2014"), format = "%d-%b %Y")

library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(dat)   
DT[order(Date), head(.SD, 1), by = list(St, Week)][duplicated(St) | duplicated(St, fromLast = TRUE)]

##     St Week       Date
## 1: 100    1 2014-06-15
## 2: 101    1 2014-06-17
## 3: 100   12 2014-08-25
## 4: 101   12 2014-08-25


library(plyr)

out <- ddply(dat, .(St, Week), function(x) head(x[order(x$Date),], 1) )
out[duplicated(out$St) | duplicated(out$St, fromLast = TRUE),]

##    St Week       Date
## 1 100    1 2014-06-15
## 2 100   12 2014-08-25
## 3 101    1 2014-06-17
## 4 101   12 2014-08-25
```

Comment: Jake - not sure this did the trick as I end up with the same number of observations in DT that I started with - expected fewer observations with the deleted rows

Comment: OK - Just saw the plyr approach - let me try.